# Textbook self-study advice

Tags: self-study, references, multivariate-analysis

I am finishing 'Introduction to the Theory of Statistics' (Mood, Graybill, Boes). Now I want to learn how to do statistics but with many variables (matrices). I am considering the following books:

Methods Multivariate Analysis (Rencher)
[https://www.amazon.com/Methods-Multivariate-Analysis-Alvin-Rencher/dp/0470178965/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1530175623&sr=1-3&keywords=alvin+rencher](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470178965)

Linear Models in Statistics (Rencher)
[https://www.amazon.com/Linear-Models-Statistics-Alvin-Rencher/dp/0471754986/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1530189102&sr=8-1&keywords=linear+models+in+statistics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471754986)

Which is more logical to be read first? Or should I read something else?

Comment: Neither. Seber and Lee Linear Regression Analysis.

Comment: @AdamO Thank you for your response. Can you please briefly explain why you recommend Seber and Lee's Linear Regression Analysis over these two books?

Comment: I should clarify: Rencher's ToCs are ambitious: they cover pure matrix algebra, and pure probability theory which should be reviewed elsewhere. [The Matrix Cookbook is a popular resource](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf). The ToC then covers many popular models: ANOVAs and linear models are covered separately. They are, in fact, equivalent procedures. To dedicate such large sections of a book on multivariate methods (which are mathematically equivalent) seems ironic and to be missing the point.

Comment: Seber and Lee is an academic standard. Their treatment is on the linear model, and presents a general case for t-tests, ordinary least squares, the Gauss Markov theorem, and maximum likelihood. This is the point of learning theory: to understand the concepts and connections from a high level perspective so that application is made easier. The algebra review is pushed to the *appendix*, and covers some aspects of computational algebra which is undoubtedly important (many CV Q's are just issues of debugging R's INLA and BLAST -linear algebra packages).

Comment: So I should study matrix algebra (from some other book) then study Seber and Lee?

Comment: You didn't ask for a book on matrix algebra.